# Getting negative value by calender function in java(Android)

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am using the below code but getting the -ve value which should not be!..

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(2013, 10, 31, 23, 00);

ctim=calendar.getTimeInMillis();//system time at shut down


calendar.clear();
calendar.set(2013, 11, 1, 1, 00);
long cTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();//system time at restart
timediff = cTime-ctim;
```

I dont know what is wrong in it..??!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem.  Months in Java are represented from 0-11, not 1-12.  The [Javadocs for the `Calendar.MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) say:

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

So the first is intrepreted as November 31st, or December 1st (`Calendar`s are "lenient" by default) because November has 30 days.  The second date is interpreted as December 1st also.

So the two times, when printed out with a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, are:

```
2013-12-01 23:00:00
2013-12-01 01:00:00
```

That's a difference of negative 22 hours, which corresponds to the `-79200000` milliseconds you're getting.

Subtract `1` from the months you're inputting:

```
calendar.set(2013, 9, 31, 23, 00);  // 9 here is October
```

and

```
calendar.set(2013, 10, 1, 1, 00);   // 10 here is November
```

and you'll get a positive difference.